# BreezeJs With Web API OData Returns "404" error when try to read Meta Data information

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

Getting 404 page not found error when try to access OData Meta data information from breeze, but i can get the information if i put url directly on Browser(without breeze).

My Server Side OData Entity Configuration is noted below.

```
var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
odataBuilder.Namespace = "BisService.Entities";
odataBuilder.EntitySet<CompanyDto>("Company").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);
config.MapODataServiceRoute("BisService", "BizService", odataBuilder.GetEdmModel());
```

I am using following config on Breeze.'

```
var serverAddress = "/BisService/";
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Company");
manager.executeQuery(query, function(data) {
      console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Show us the URL that the breeze client sends (get it from browser dev tools) ... the one with the 404 ... and then show us the URL that you say works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues similar to this while attempting to implement breezejs with odata.

After reading the [OData on the Server](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-server) article on breezejs.com, we decided that Web Api would suit us just fine.

If you need to continue down the odata path, see the [Open Data](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata) article.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what may have been the same issue today. In my case, I traced it down to the addition of the following header in the request:

```
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
```

This is added by [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/) and my work around was to comment out the following line in `datajs-1.1.2.js`:

```
 if (!assigned(request.headers.MaxDataServiceVersion)) {
     //request.headers.MaxDataServiceVersion = handler.maxDataServiceVersion || "1.0";
 }
```

which is line **2334** in the version I have.